# Is $0^0$ undefined?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why $\lim_{x->0}log(x^x)=0$ ?. This means $0^0=1$?

For WolframAlpha $\lim_{x->0}log(x^x)=0$ but   $0^0$ is not defined.

Comment: $x\to0$ does not mean $x=0$  Here in fact, $x\to0^+$

Comment: What's the downvote for? Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: Again the Power Less Monster ? http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zeroth-Power

Comment: As we see,  
$lon(x^x)=xlogx$.  
$0^0$ is not defined,  
$lim_{x\rightarrow0}log(x^x)=0$ is because of that $f(x)=x$ converges faster than $g(x)=\frac{1}{log(x)}$ at the point (0,0).  
As we knew $\frac{1}{log(x)}*log(x)=1$,so,when $x\rightarrow0$, $f(x)*g(x)=o(1)$.  That is to say $lim_{x\rightarrow0}log(x^x)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some calculations $0^0 = 1$.
However that does not seem logical, because for example:

- $2^{-2} = 0.25; 0^{-2} = 0$
- $2^{-1} = 0.5; 0^{-1} = 0$
- $2^0 = 2^{-1} * 2 = 1; 0^0 = 0^{-1} * 0 = 0 ?!?!$

From these calculations we "know" that $0^0 = 0$. But $x \in \mathbb{R} \implies x^0 = 1$ ! And that's why the $0^0$ is undefined: because it has more than one value and breaks algebra with $0 = 1$...

Comment: This is not correct, as $0^{-1}={1\over 0}$ is not equal to $0$. Similarly for $0^{-2}={1\over 0^2}$, which is also undefined for the same reason (division by zero).

Comment: I didn't use fractions. Also, $0^x$ is $0$ for every $x \neq 0$.

Comment: No, only for $x>0$. The reason is that you get trouble with $a^{-b}={1\over a^b}$ otherwise.

Comment: @ciuak, It 'seems' to have more than one value, and thus is regarded 'indeterminate'